# How to use clip-path in an animation?

Tags: css, animation, svg, clip

I've read a bunch of posts and been playing around with trying to animate a clip-path. At this point I can only get it show the clip-path in Firefox and it always pins the path to 0,0.

Here is an example code -> http://jsfiddle.net/justintense/4torLok9/1/

I'm using a simple inline SVG as the path:

```
    <clipPath id="clipping">

        <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="40,35 40,15 20,35   "/>
        <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="0,35 20,35 0,15     "/>

        <circle id="white_overlay_9_" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="20" cy="18.77" r="7.393"/>
    </clipPath>
```

I'm unsure if what I trying to do is even possible so am just looking for pointer so I can get this one track.

**Edit:**

I'm trying to recreate the behaviour similar to this site --------> http://uppymama.com/

[image]

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basic left to right slide. If you look at .full > div > div you can see it positioned at left:50%. Was hoping that by changing the left it would move the clip-path too. But I don't think it works like that.

Comment: PS. im trying to recreate the pointer (bottom of nav) -> http://uppymama.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Defining the `clipPath`:

You don't need three elements in your `clipPath`, you could simplify it to a single `path` element.

```
<path d="M0,0 L40,0 L20,15z M20,5 m-5,0 a5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a5,5 0 1,0 -10,0z" />
```

---

#### Applying the `clipPath` to the `div`:

For applying the `clip-path`, if you want <kbd>[**maximum browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)</kbd>, you could import the `div` into an `svg` element through `svg`'s `foreignObject` element. Then, apply the `clip-path` to the `foreignObject`.

Here's the <kbd>[**browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20clip-path)</kbd>, if you apply the `clip-path` through CSS.

---

#### Animating the `clipPath`:

Now, for aligning the pointer right in the middle of the menu item, you'll need JavaScript to do some calculations and animate the `clipPath`'s `transform` property.

1. When page loads calculate the distance from the left window corner to the first menu-item and move the `clip-path` to that co-ordinate.
2. When the window resizes, calculate the distance again and move the pointer.
3. When the menu item is clicked, calculate the distance and animate the pointer using `setTimeout()` and *synchronous code* until it reaches the correct position.

> *Synchronous code* means that the operations are performed one at a time and that, until one operation is over, the code execution is blocked from moving onto the next operation.

---

#### Exact replica of that [site](http://uppymama.com/):

As you can see on that site, the pointer isn't centered.

My solution will always center the pointer depending on the width of the menu item.

<kbd>**Demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/ogzzGv)**</kbd>

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
var clipPath = document.getElementById('clip-path');
var lastActive = items[0];
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var x = this.getBoundingClientRect().left + (this.offsetWidth / 2) - 20;
    animStart(x);
    lastActive = this;
  })
}

function animStart(end) {
  for (start = 0; start <= end; start += 0.1) {
    anim(start);
  }
}

function anim(start) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    clipPath.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + start + ', 0)');
  }, 1 * start);
}

function align() {
  var x = lastActive.getBoundingClientRect().left + (lastActive.offsetWidth / 2) - 20;
  animStart(x);
}

function resize() {
  var x = lastActive.getBoundingClientRect().left + (lastActive.offsetWidth / 2) - 20;
  clipPath.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', 0)');
}
window.onresize = resize;
window.onload = align;
```

```css
body {
  background: #222222;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-container {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, palegoldenrod 5px, palegreen 10px, palegreen 15px, paleturquoise 15px, paleturquoise 20px, plum 20px, plum 25px);
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 17px 20px;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  color: seagreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, palegoldenrod 5px, palegreen 10px, palegreen 15px, paleturquoise 15px, paleturquoise 20px, plum 20px, plum 25px);
}
#clip-path {
  transition: 0.5s transform;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item">Home</div>
      <div id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item">About</div>
      <div id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item">Services</div>
      <div id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item">Locations</div>
      <div id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item">Contact Us</div>
    </div>
    <svg style="position: relative; top: -1px;" class="svg-defs" height="35" width="100%">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipping">
          <path id="clip-path" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L20,15z M20,6 m-5,0 a5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a5,5 0 1,0 -10,0z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <foreignObject x="0" y="0" clip-path="url(#clipping)" height="35" width="100%">
        <div id="bottom"></div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

#### Even Better:

Retaining the last position of the pointer.

<kbd>**Demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/XJjjYO)**</kbd>

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
var clipPath = document.getElementById('clip-path');
var last = items[0];
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var x = this.getBoundingClientRect().left + (this.offsetWidth / 2) - 20;
    var currentX = clipPath.getAttribute('transform').replace('translate(', '');
    currentX = parseInt(currentX.replace(', 0)', ''), 10);
    animStart(currentX, x);
    last = this;
  })
}

function animStart(begin, end) {
  if (begin < end) {
    for (start = begin; start <= end; start += 0.1) {
      anim(start);
    }
  } else {
    var c = end;
    for (start = begin; end <= start; start -= 0.1) {
      animD(start, c);
      c += 0.1
    }
  }
}

function anim(start) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    clipPath.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + start + ', 0)');
  }, 1 * start);
}

function animD(start, c) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    clipPath.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + start + ', 0)');
  }, 1 * c);
}

function align() {
  var x = last.getBoundingClientRect().left + (last.offsetWidth / 2) - 20;
  animStart(0, x);
}

function resize() {
  var x = last.getBoundingClientRect().left + (last.offsetWidth / 2) - 20;
  clipPath.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', 0)');
}
window.onresize = resize;
window.onload = align;
```

```css
body {
  background: #222222;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-container {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, palegoldenrod 5px, palegreen 10px, palegreen 15px, paleturquoise 15px, paleturquoise 20px, plum 20px, plum 25px);
}
.nav {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 17px 20px;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  color: seagreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, palegoldenrod 5px, palegreen 10px, palegreen 15px, paleturquoise 15px, paleturquoise 20px, plum 20px, plum 25px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item">Home</div>
      <div id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item">About</div>
      <div id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item">Services</div>
      <div id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item">Locations</div>
      <div id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item">Contact Us</div>
    </div>
    <svg style="position: relative; top: -1px;" class="svg-defs" height="35" width="100%">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipping">
          <path id="clip-path" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L20,15z M20,6 m-5,0 a5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a5,5 0 1,0 -10,0z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <foreignObject x="0" y="0" clip-path="url(#clipping)" height="35" width="100%">
        <div id="bottom"></div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your awesome. Thx chipChocolate.py! I like the foreignObject concept so will give that a try!